# Convert a string in given format to json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I got an object in below format from back end;

```
Array ([one] => [two] => 1000)
```

I want this in JSON format, How can I convert? I'm using online JSON parser. unfortunately it failed to do the job.

Comment: Use `json_encode($your_array)` while sending it from php code.

Comment: "PHP array into JSON using jQuery" doesn't make sense. You can't use jQuery in PHP.

Comment: Hope that, you will get better response if you add sample input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PHP to convert your array to JSON

`<?php json_encode(your_array); ?>`

while sending the code from PHP side and convert back to array at the client side using

```
JSON.parse(response);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use php to convert your array to json

```
<?php json_encode(your_array); ?>
```

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a pure javascript-jquery answer.

Comment: thank you for considering my question